# Data type of attribute on join model in Active Record/Rails 3.2/PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have models `Client` and `Sessions` and a join model `ClientSessionAssignment` that associates the two. `ClientSessionAssignment` has one join column `score` which is defined as `decimal` type in `schema.rb`. I'm using `has_many` with `select` to preload `score` values when querying instances of `Client` as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions,
    :through => :client_session_assignments,
    :select => 'sessions.*, client_session_assignments.score'
end
```

Despite `score` being defined as `decimal` in the database, when it is accessed this way, Active Record represents it as a string, i.e. `Client.first.sessions.first.score.class` yields `String` when I would expect it to yield `BigDecimal`. Consequently, I have to cast or convert scores obtained this way to `BigDecimal` before I can perform any calculations on them.

UPDATES

It turns out that only the `postgresql` database adapter exhibits this strange behaviour. I have filed https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13044 to track this in the Rails bug tracker on GitHub: full test case is at https://gist.github.com/rcook/7670071.

Comment: What is the output when you remove the :select option in your association declaration and run Client.first.sessions.first.score.class again?

Comment: Without the `:select` option, then `score` is not added to `Client.first.sessions.first`.

Comment: Oh right. Try this instead: Client.first.client_session_assignments.first.score.class

Comment: This returns `BigDecimal`.

Comment: What database you are using? and can you post the code in schema where decimal column is declared and can you post any sample app in github, because I tried with rails 3.2.13 and mysql db, its working fine(returns `BigDecimal` calling through associations)

Comment: PostgreSQL and the column is declared with type `decimal` in the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Rails 3.2.x:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13044

It's been fixed in Rails 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like activerecord isn't type casting properly through the association. Try overwriting the accessor method in your join model:

```
class ClientSessionAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def score
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_decimal super
  end
end
```

This should return a BigDecimal when you call `Client.first.sessions.first.score`

Comment: I'll try that tonight. This looks like it'll work around this behaviour. Do you know if this is a bug in Active Record?

Comment: Just found out from your question, it might be.